# Ruby equivalent of Python's list() for enumerables

Tags: python, ruby, list, enumerable

In Python, we can use the `list()` method on an enumerable to create an ordered list based on the enumerator's items. How would you accomplish this in a Ruby enumerable?

This is currently what I'm using, but it feels a bit hack-ish:

```
data = []
e = # .. enumerable ..
e.each do |d|
  data << d
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do Array(list) :

```
(1..10).to_a #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Same for other *iterables*

```
my_array.to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out:--

```
e = # .. enumerable ..
e.to_a
```

or

```
e.entries
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be clever, you could also play with several other enumerable methods. For example:

```
enumerable.map { | x | x }

enumerable.select { true }
```

...or my personal favorite,

```
enumerable.inject( [ ] ) { | c, i | c + [ i ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python `list("a")` results in a list; in Ruby `"a".to_a` gives an error.
The splat operator called an an 'unsplattable`object results in the object itself. So maybe this is more equivalent to Pythons`list`:

```
a = ("a".."f").each_cons(2)
[*a] #=> [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "d"], ["d", "e"], ["e", "f"]]

[*"a"] #=> ["a"]
```